# Dedicated Scala String interpolation

Tags: string, scala, implicit-conversion, string-interpolation

For a given `Map` of constants

```
val ctt = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
```

how to define a `String` interpolator `c` where

```
c"a"
```

delivers `List(1)` ?

**Note** Already considered [String Interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) but still unclear how to proceed.

**Update**

```
c"a,b"
res: List(1,2)

c" a, b  "
res: List(1,2)

c"a,w"
res: List(1)

c"w"
res: List()
```

Comment: This explains how to write your own string interpolators (under "Advanced Usage"): [String Interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)

Comment: @Jesper many thanks, had looked at it but still unclear how to proceed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works:

```
scala> val ctt = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
ctt: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)

scala> implicit class CttHelper(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
     |   def c(args: Any*): Int = ctt(sc.parts.head)
     | }
defined class CttHelper

scala> c"a"
res0: Int = 1
```

Or for your updated version:

```
implicit class CttHelper(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def c(args: Any*): List[Int] =
    sc.parts.head.split(',').map(_.trim).toList.flatMap(ctt.get)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> c"a,w"
res5: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> c"a,b"
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> c" a, b  "
res7: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> c"a,w"
res8: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> c"w"
res9: List[Int] = List()
```

You probably want to check that `sc.parts` has a single element, though, unless you actually want to do something with interpolated variables.